# Search ill encoded characters in a file on Linux

Tags: linux, encoding, utf-8, vi

I have a lot of huge CSV files, some of them contain ill encoded characters: in vi, I see things like "<8f>" or "<8e>", for example.
First, I wanted to search and replace (:%s) all the characters, but it will be a very long process because I will have to do this everytime I have to handle a file, and I'm not always sure whether new characters are here.
Is it possible to detect such characters, so that I can extract lines containing ill encoded characters?
A simple command may exist, taking a file for argument and creating a file containing only the lines with a problem.

I don't know if I explain me very well...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code. But first, see [How to complete a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't know what else to say. I don't have any code, that's the point of my question. I can give you an example of what I have when I use the "vi" command:
"vi file.csv" gives me this:
`NOMS
PR<8f>NOMS` and I'd like to detect this <8f>.

Answer (score 1):

You could use :g/char/p [vim] to print all the lines in a given file, or the bash utility grep:

```
grep -lr 'char1\|char2\|char2' .
```

Will output all the files in a directory containing any of the chars you have listed (the -r makes it recursive and the -l lists only the filenames, rather than all the line matches.

Comment: Thanks F Biggs for having taken the time to reply.
I found something else, what I'll post in a few hours on my github and post the link here.